# Array empty when trying to populate tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a second section which is where `section.indexPath = 0`. This section is objects which is generated from distance between two locations which is done in the didUpdateToLocation. When trying to populate the tableview with the objects from the array it shows:

```
index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

How can i show the nearStoresArray in the tableview without getting the empty array error.

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Here it gives an error and say that nearStoresArray is empty. I guess thats because the tableview is showing before the `didUpdateToLocation`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        indexNo = [nearStoresArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%d", [nearStoresArray count]);

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            indexNo = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            indexNo = [storesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

    }

        cell.textLabel.text = [indexNo valueForKey:@"name"];


    return cell;
}
```

Here is the didUpdateToLocation method. This method creates the nearStoresArray, which works fine.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager = nil;

    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {

        for (int i = 0; i < [storesArray count]; i++) {

            CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
            CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];

            CLLocation *checkPosition = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

            CLLocationDistance distance = [checkPosition distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];


            float distanceInKm = distance / 1000;


            if (distanceInKm < 5) {

                [nearStoresArray removeAllObjects];

                [nearStoresArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"], @"id",
                [[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"], @"name",
                [[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lat"], @"lat",
                [[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"long"], @"long",
                [[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"address"], @"address",
                [[storesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"zip"], @"zip"
                , nil]];

               NSLog(@"%@", nearStoresArray);


            }


            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }



    }


}
```

numberOfRows Method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section==0) {
        return [nearStoresArray count];
    } else if (section==1) {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            return [filteredArray count];
        } else {
            return [storesArray count];
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }




}
```

Comment: where you have defined array? add that code, also how you are defining numberOfRows method?

Comment: i defined it in the viewDidLoad: nearStoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ]; numberOfRows added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly Access Section Like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return [nearStoresArray count];

    }
    else if (section == 1) {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            return [filteredArray count];
        } 
        else {
            return [storesArray count];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to update `numberOfRowsInSection` method, like below -

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return [nearStoresArray count];

    }
    else if (section == 1) {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            return [filteredArray count];
        } 
        else {
            return [storesArray count];
        }
    }
    else {
        return 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is `indexPath` defined?

Comment: So now it's exactly the same as the OPs code except it doesn't handle cases where `section > 1`.  Can you explain what that achieves, as it's not clear to me.

Comment: earlier his code was not handling section conditions at all. I think he has updated this. However if his problem is not solved, i am going to delete this answer.